# Flutter: How to use Markdown in showDialog?

Tags: flutter, markdown, rendering

I'm trying to use Markdown (from package **flutter_markdown: ^0.6.6**) in a dialog box. Following example returns error:

> RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic
> dimensions.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Package flutter_markdown'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: HelpButtonWithDialog(
          title: 'markdown test',
          content: '# Help Text\n\n* Text line 1\n*Text Line 2',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HelpButtonWithDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  HelpButtonWithDialog({
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
      onPressed: () => showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: Markdown(
            data: content,
            shrinkWrap: true,
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text('OK'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm... with this example, I cannot experience like your error.(I change a markdown package version for my low flutter version.

Comment: Maybe the version is the problem but I need full null safety.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround by using *Dialog* and copying parts from *AlertDialog*. I also filed an enhancement request https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89464 to the Flutter team to get this proper.

Here is the workaround code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Package flutter_markdown'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
                'flutter_markdown: Please add example how to use in showDialog'),
            Text('https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89464'),
            HelpButtonWithDialog(
              title: 'markdown test',
              content: '# Help Text\n\n* Text line 1\n* Text Line 2',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HelpButtonWithDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  HelpButtonWithDialog({
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final DialogTheme dialogTheme = DialogTheme.of(context);
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
      onPressed: () => showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Dialog(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 24.0),
                child: DefaultTextStyle(
                  style:
                      dialogTheme.titleTextStyle ?? theme.textTheme.headline6!,
                  child: Text(title),
                ),
              ),
              MarkdownBody(
                data: content,
                shrinkWrap: true,
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```